# How do I cache a initial connection made to a database through REST JERSEY

Tags: java, rest, amazon-kinesis

I have a situation where I would be receiving JSON objects continuously on to my`REST` server. I would then put the objects into a `AWS Kinesis` stream. I would initialize a connection to kinesis stream while putting the object into it. This init is happening for every object and thats an overload. I would like to cache the connection to kinesis for some duration. I looked at `REST HTTP Caching` where in the object would be cached but not the connection. Any way to get this done.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AWS Kinesis and how it works, but this is usually done by using a connection pool (I'm assuming you connect via REST to Kinesis). Jersey on its own doesn't have a connection pool, but you can configure one in Apache HTTPClient and then pass the httpclient to jersey. This email thread from the Jersey user list has an example of how to do this: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/jersey-apache-client-connection-pool-configuration-td5149765.html

Comment: I am basically initializing a connection to put the object every 1 second. I will have to use a init() and putData() methods. Where in init() method does use the credentials and kinesis client to to initialize kinesis. I think this could not be done using http. However, I have tried using JAVA Singleton class to initialize the object once and not more than that so the initialize is done only once. But, this doesnt seems to be the best idea.